# Automatically move sharepoint files to local server

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Flow process that saves PDF attachments on an email to a SharePoint folder.

I want to move them from SharePoint to a local folder on a server. I was hoping, I can run as a PowerShell script as task may be. But really can't find anything or if it is possible.  I've seen some stuff where you can push from local folder to SharePoint but didn't have any success reverse engineering the script.

Thanks.
Gary

Comment: Thanks, the Get-PnpFile process worked. Need to work on something that downloads all. But a lot further ahead now.

Comment: You can use the Get-PNPListItem command to pull all of the files from a list or library.  Example: $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $YourLibrary -PageSize 1000 .  Then do a for each loop on the $ListItems

Comment: Hi @Taco_Buffet , thanks.  I've been trying that but it seems it's grabbing all files in my library.  I just want the ones in a particular folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try FolderServerRelativeUrl parameter?

```
$devConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://sharepointed.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA/siteB" -Credentials $myLoginInfo -ReturnConnection

$folderName = "/sites/siteA/siteB/Shared Documents/myfolder/anotherfolder"

$folderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Shared Documents" -FolderServerRelativeUrl $folderName -Connection $devConn
```

You could also use Get-PnPFolderItem.

```
$devConn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://sharepointed.sharepoint.com/sites/siteA/siteB" -Credentials $myLoginInfo -ReturnConnection   

$folderName = "/Shared Documents/myfolder/anotherfolder"

$folderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderName -Connection $devConn

foreach($item in $folderItems)
{
    Write-Host $item.Name
}
```

Links:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfolderitem?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Thanks.  That helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP PowerShell to get a file from SharePoint location to download and save it. Use Get-PnPFile command as below.

```
Get-PnPFile -Url _catalogs/themes/15/company.spcolor -Path c:\temp -FileName company.spcolor -AsFile
```

The `-Url` parameter should be a site relative URL

for more reference check [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)