# Why did SharePoint erase metadata from photos?

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata

At my job, our main server went down and our IT department had to migrate those files to SharePoint to allow us to access those files. My job is to archive, categorize, and organize some of those files. Once I downloaded the necessary photos, metadata was erased from them. The date created is now the date I downloaded them. I know that is not true. How do I extract the photos from SharePoint while keeping the original metadata? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a PowerShell script or use some kind of migration software like sharegate there is no out of the box option.

Here is one thread that should help you start [Automatically move sharepoint files to local server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283922/automatically-move-sharepoint-files-to-local-server)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. When you download a file from SharePoint the file gets a new created date. Same happens when you download & zip a set of SharePoint files. You loose the original SharePoint create and modify dates.

Using PowerShell script is an option.
Using OneDrive for Business client may also offer a solution. I would expect the local files to retain the original SharePoint modify date.
Another option is to use 3rd party apps. See [list](https://collab365.com/best-document-management-solutions-for-sharepoint/)
There are apps that allow you download a set of files and capture the SharePoint modify dates into the zip. So after expanding the zip file you end up with files having the SharePoint modify date.

Note: some of the apps take this to the next level by exposing the actual create/modify dates in the photos itself. This also includes GPS coordinates, date time taken etc...